# Can I deploy a public key for signature verification in a docker image such that it is protected against modification?

Tags: docker, public-key-encryption

Our customers need to install our software on premise, on servers that possibly do not have internet access. To make this possible, we ship docker images of our software to them.
However we also want to be able to change license information of our software without requiring them to update the whole software.
In order to make this secure, we want to send the customer data that contains the license changes and is signed on our local servers.
The signature must be verified by our software which as mentioned is running in the container. Consequently our software needs to know the public key to check the signature against, but that public key should be protected against modification by the customer.

Is there a way to make the public key available inside the docker image, for example as env variable, but in a way that makes hard for the customer to change it?

Comment: **Docker is designed to allow easy modifications**. This says it all; so to make it hard, first of all, don't use Docker; or, rather, this is a common container format, so don't use containerization. What to use instead? It's your problem, but being in the place of a customer I'd cut ties with the partner who intends "to make it hard" for me, no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to make the public key available inside the docker image, for example as env variable, but in a way that makes it impossible or very hard for the customer to change it?

No.

If you let your customer run your docker image, you let them run it. What you propose is essentially DRM, which doesn't work.

Comment: ok making it impossible is impossible, so much is clear. how about making just it hard, as mentioned in the question.
Like, we could just somewhere hidden in our code hardcode a hash of the public key, that could offer some basic protection against modification.
So the question is, is there anything like this that docker provides?

Comment: DRM doesn't work. Microsoft has attempted to make it hard. Hollywood attempted to make it hard. And so forth...

Comment: In order to conclude "doesn't work" you must be making a lot of assumptions, about the particular use case, about the users, about the definition of 'hard'.
From your answer I do not see any actionable way to move forward.

Comment: If the customer *wants* to break it, DRM doesn't work. Look at e.g. Windows XP activation model. Did it curtail piracy? Nope. If the customer *doesn't* want to break it, DRM works - but so does anything.

Comment: The conditions for windows or DRM for large content are very very different to ours.
It seems to make more sense to compare it to putting a lock on a bike. a drunk at night will steal the bike if it has no lock. but if someone really wants to break it, they still can.

Comment: No; it's exactly the same. It's not DRM that keeps people honest; it's business agreements and laws that incur punishments for piracy.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this is not in any way helpful to us.

Comment: How many examples of failed DRM schemes is needed?